# Gitlab next to Virtualmin and Apache with LetsEncrypt

Tags: nginx, gitlab, apache2, virtualmin

I have Virtualmin and it has apache and primary domain and encryption by Let's Encrypt.

I install gitlab on the subdomain and port 8443, but it doesn't work for me.

Turns on on the port but not on the subdomain.

I don't know how to connect a subdomain to open gitlab.

I don't know how to add a certificate from Virtualmin to a subdomain.

How do you do these two things?

Should I do it outside Virtualmin?

Answer (score 0):

if you need a script like GitLab to run on a subdomain of the website, you need to create a sub server.

login to Virtualmin, select your domain, click create Virtual server,

from top tabs, select sub servers.

not if you want to create subdomain git.example.com, just type 'git' in domain and press [TAB].

in enable-feature section, select Setup SSL website too? and click create server.

after the sub server is created, go to the SSL section and request for let's encrypt the certificate.

To enable port 8443, go to webmin, networking, firewalld, on the list of ports and services, click add allowed port, add port 8443. and apply configuration.

just stop and start firewall to take effects.